Does the Unsung Hero badge count answers to questions from deleted users?
I just read this question and tried out the linked query which states that I have 15 accepted answers with 3 zero-score answers. Counting them manually on my Profile gave me 21 answers with 5 zero-score answers. After reading a bit more on meta, I learned that self-accepted answers don't count, which is the case for 2 of my answers, neither do answers count that are less than 10 days old, which excludes another 2 answers (including one zero-score answer).
This still leaves 17 accepted answers in total and 4 zero-score answers. I changed the query to show me the question titles, compared them to the list on my profile page and figured out that the two answers which were not counted have one thing in common: the user who asked the question does not exist anymore.
Do these answers count for the Unsung Hero badge, or is this just a bug in the query?

Seems like a bug in the query, as far as I know these count.
See a forked query which returns the 17 and 4 you've found yourself.

To add some context q.OwnerUserId != ##UserId## ended up being false because q.OwnerUserId was null.

@AbdulAzizBarkat interesting, I would have expected that to be true

@Aemyl in fact it results in null (got previous comment wrong). See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405272/why-does-null-something-return-false
